# React native Navigate to Root screen

Tags: react-native, navigation

In my project i am using StackNavigator for navigation, the project contains total 5 screens and i want to move from last screen to first.
I have used below code for navigate from one screen to another.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('FinalView')
```

Need to move from 'finalView' to 'Home'.
tried many method like

```
this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation.navigate('Home')
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```